# What is the difference between didn’t get to sleep and “toss and turn”?

Tags: meaning, conversation

I saw this saying in a conversation book:

> I didn’t get to sleep for two or three hours. Then after that I tossed and turned all night.

And I’ve consulted [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toss%20and%20turn) dictionary.

Doesn’t “toss and turn” mean not able to sleep?

Comment: The two are related but by no means synonymous.  "Toss and turn" is a fairly literal description of the activity -- moving about restlessly.  You may "toss and turn" *during* your sleep, or the activity may *prevent* you from sleeping (though the latter is the more common use).

Answer (score 11):

"Toss and turn" is most often used to indicate a restless sleep. The idea is that while you may fall asleep, you also move around frequently and don't sleep very soundly.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/toss-and-turn):

> to move around restlessly while sleeping or trying to sleep

Comment: Do you have a reference for the "restless sleep" usage being "most often"?
 I would have thought the insomnia meaning was more common, as in the Bobby Lewis song *Tossin' and Turnin'* ("I couldn't sleep at all last night/.../Well I was tossin' and turnin'/turnin' and tossin'/tossin' and turnin' all night" etc.)

Comment: @1006a I'd say the quote from the original post is at least an example of the "restless sleep" meaning.  It's certainly how I use the phrase (native AmE)

Comment: I didn't say the restless sleep meaning was unheard-of, just that you should have a reference if you're going to state definitively that it is the primary usage. I'm also a native AmE speaker, and use it primarily the other way; we also have one example of each usage; so now we have an N of 4 with 50/50 results. In general, answers are better if they are referenced—a dictionary entry, a corpus search, reference to a linguistic study, etc.—rather than purely opinion-based.

Comment: @1006a fair enough.

Answer (score 6):

*To get to sleep* means *to **manage** to fall asleep*.
*To toss and turn* means *to **move around** restlessly while sleeping or **trying** to fall asleep.* Therefore, these two expressions are not synonymous. You toss and turn when you can't get to sleep.

Answer (score 2):

"I didn't get to sleep for two or three hours" could mean that the person wasn't *trying* to fall asleep -- maybe they were listening to music or reading a book.

"Toss and turn" means they were trying -- and failing -- to fall asleep.